# Having an exception when using TopLink on WebLogic

Tags: ejb, weblogic, toplink

I get the below exception when trying to run an EJB application using TopLink on WebLogic application server.

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: TblPkgFeature.getFeaturesData not found:
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.getDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:422)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.setParameterInternal(EJBQueryImpl.java:657)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:202)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at weblogic.persistence.InterceptingInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(InterceptingInvocationHandlerImpl.java:29)
at $Proxy110.setParameter(Unknown Source)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.service.impl.PartDetailServiceImpl.getPackageData(PartDetailServiceImpl.java:170)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.service.impl.PartDetailService_888km8_PartDetailServiceRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:34)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.service.impl.PartDetailService_888km8_PartDetailServiceRemoteImpl.getPackageData(Unknown Source)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.service.impl.PartDetailService_888km8_PartDetailServiceRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:202)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:463)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:274)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.service.impl.PartDetailService_888km8_PartDetailServiceRemoteImpl_12120_WLStub.getPackageData(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:84)
at $Proxy111.getPackageData(Unknown Source)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.server.rmi.client.PartDetailServiceRmiClient.getPackageData(PartDetailServiceRmiClient.java:108)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.gui.server.services.PartDetailRemoteServiceImpl.getPackageData(PartDetailRemoteServiceImpl.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at com.siliconexpert.avago.gui.server.services.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:47)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

The above exception is thrown on the below line:

```java
List<TblPkgFeature> list = 
            em.createNamedQuery("TblPkgFeature.getFeaturesData").setParameter("pkgTypeId", GetFeaturesData.PACKAGE.getCode()).setParameter("type", "package").getResultList();
```

Also when I changed this method `em.createNamedQuery("TblPkgFeature.getFeaturesData")` by the method

```java
em.createQuery("select new com.siliconexpert.avago.model.TblPkgFeature(p.fetId, p.fetName, p.fetDisplayName, o.fetDefention, p.unit) " +
            " from TblPkgFeature p left outer join p.tblOthersFetDef o where (lower(o.type) =:type or o.type is null )" +
            " and p.display=1 and p.pkgTypeId =:pkgTypeId order by p.cmDisplayOrder")
```

it worked successfully and the exception wasn't thrown.

By the way both queries are the same, but the difference is that I placed the query in the method parameter of the "createQuery()" method.

The below is the entity bean that contains the NamedQuery:

```java
    package com.siliconexpert.avago.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
 * The persistent class for the TBL_PKG_FEATURES database table.
 * 
 */

@NamedQueries
({
    @NamedQuery(name="TblPkgFeature.getFeaturesData", query="select new com.siliconexpert.avago.model.TblPkgFeature(p.fetId, p.fetName, p.fetDisplayName, o.fetDefention, p.unit) " +
            " from TblPkgFeature p left outer join p.tblOthersFetDef o where (lower(o.type) =:type or o.type is null )" +
            " and p.display=1 and p.pkgTypeId =:pkgTypeId order by p.cmDisplayOrder ") //and p.fetId<>39
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PKG_FEATURES")
public class TblPkgFeature implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8604710446605212000L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FET_ID")
    private long fetId;

    @Column(name = "CM_DISPLAY_ORDER")
    private long cmDisplayOrder;

    @Column(name = "DATA_LENGHT")
    private long dataLenght;

    @Column(name = "DATA_TYPE")
    private String dataType;

    private long display;

    @Column(name = "FET_DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String fetDisplayName;

    @Column(name = "FET_HEADER_ORDER")
    private long fetHeaderOrder;

    @Column(name = "FET_NAME")
    private String fetName;

    @Column(name = "OLD_NAME")
    private String oldName;

    @Column(name = "PKG_TYPE_ID")
    private long pkgTypeId;

    @Column(name = "QUALITY_AV")
    private long qualityAv;

    @Column(name = "TBL_NAME")
    private String tblName;

    private String unit;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FET_NAME", referencedColumnName="FET_NAME", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private TblOthersFetDef tblOthersFetDef;

    @Transient
    private String fetDefinition;

    public TblPkgFeature()
    {
    }

    public TblPkgFeature(long fetId, String fetDisplayName)
    {
        super();
        this.fetId = fetId;
        this.fetDisplayName = fetDisplayName;
    }

    public TblOthersFetDef getTblOthersFetDef()
    {
        return tblOthersFetDef;
    }

    public void setTblOthersFetDef(TblOthersFetDef tblOthersFetDef)
    {
        this.tblOthersFetDef = tblOthersFetDef;
    }

    public TblPkgFeature(long fetId, String fetDisplayName, String fetDefinition, String unit)
    {
        this(fetId, fetDisplayName);
        this.fetDefinition = fetDefinition;
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public TblPkgFeature(long fetId, String fetName, String fetDisplayName, String fetDefinition, String unit)
    {
        this(fetId, fetDisplayName, fetDefinition, unit);
        this.fetName = fetName;
    }

    public String getFetDefinition()
    {
        return fetDefinition;
    }

    public void setFetDefinition(String fetDefinition)
    {
        this.fetDefinition = fetDefinition;
    }

    public long getFetId()
    {
        return this.fetId;
    }

    public void setFetId(long fetId)
    {
        this.fetId = fetId;
    }

    public long getCmDisplayOrder()
    {
        return this.cmDisplayOrder;
    }

    public void setCmDisplayOrder(long cmDisplayOrder)
    {
        this.cmDisplayOrder = cmDisplayOrder;
    }

    public long getDataLenght()
    {
        return this.dataLenght;
    }

    public void setDataLenght(long dataLenght)
    {
        this.dataLenght = dataLenght;
    }

    public String getDataType()
    {
        return this.dataType;
    }

    public void setDataType(String dataType)
    {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public long getDisplay()
    {
        return this.display;
    }

    public void setDisplay(long display)
    {
        this.display = display;
    }

    public String getFetDisplayName()
    {
        return this.fetDisplayName;
    }

    public void setFetDisplayName(String fetDisplayName)
    {
        this.fetDisplayName = fetDisplayName;
    }

    public long getFetHeaderOrder()
    {
        return this.fetHeaderOrder;
    }

    public void setFetHeaderOrder(long fetHeaderOrder)
    {
        this.fetHeaderOrder = fetHeaderOrder;
    }

    public String getFetName()
    {
        return this.fetName;
    }

    public void setFetName(String fetName)
    {
        this.fetName = fetName;
    }

    public String getOldName()
    {
        return this.oldName;
    }

    public void setOldName(String oldName)
    {
        this.oldName = oldName;
    }

    public long getPkgTypeId()
    {
        return this.pkgTypeId;
    }

    public void setPkgTypeId(long pkgTypeId)
    {
        this.pkgTypeId = pkgTypeId;
    }

    public long getQualityAv()
    {
        return this.qualityAv;
    }

    public void setQualityAv(long qualityAv)
    {
        this.qualityAv = qualityAv;
    }

    public String getTblName()
    {
        return this.tblName;
    }

    public void setTblName(String tblName)
    {
        this.tblName = tblName;
    }

    public String getUnit()
    {
        return this.unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit)
    {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you have created `NamedQuery` and how does it look like? Maybe you got some typo?

Comment: Thanks Geinmachi for you reply, I have updated the post with Entity Bean which contains the NamedQuery which I am trying to call.

Comment: In your server startup log, do you see a message about deploying the named query?

Comment: Thanks hugh for your reply, I've checked the logs but I didn't find any message about deploying the named query.